# How can I move a headline and all siblings under another headline?

Tags: org-mode

If I have an outline that looks like this:

```
* a
* b
** c
** d
** e
```

How can I most efficiently move c and d and e under a? And what if, instead of a and b being in the same .org file, a and b are in different .org files?

Comment: If this is an `org-mode` buffer, how can `a` and `b` be in different files?  Are you referring to an `org-agenda-mode` (e.g., `*Org Agenda*`) buffer?

Comment: Have a look at the org **refile** section of the manual:  https://orgmode.org/manual/Refile-and-copy.html#Refile-and-copy  See also the functions `org-move-item-down`; `org-move-item-up`; `org-move-subtree-down`; `org-move-subtree-up`.

Comment: Note that the `org-agenda-mode` buffer also has a **refile** command with the same keyboard shortcut i.e., `C-c C-w`:  https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html  And see this related thread that deals with `org-refile-targets`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200312/refile-from-one-file-to-other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include all the siblings in a region and then use `org-refile` (`C-c C-w`) to move them under the desired heading.